# Drop in Fps while Reading From Camera

Tags: camera, gstreamer, frame-rate, v4l2, logitech

I have Two cameras, one is microsoft and another one is logitech.

For both cameras i have used the below pipeline.

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=640,height=480 ! fpsdisplaysink
```

**For Microsoft :**

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 678, dropped: 10, current: 30.10, average: 29.71

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 678, dropped: 10, current: 30.10, average: 29.71

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 678, dropped: 10, current: 30.10, average: 29.71

**But, when i moved my hand very close to the camera, or i closed the camera with my hand then the results are,**

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 2554, dropped: 44, **current: 7.52**, average: 28.93

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0/GstTextOverlay:fps-display-text-overlay: text = rendered: 2558, dropped: 44, **current: 7.51,** average: 28.81

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 2558, dropped: 44, **current: 7.51,** average: 28.81

**There is a Huge Drop in Frame Rate.
What is the problem in this scenario and how to resolve it??**

**For Logitech:**

Same pipeline i had used, but the results are as follows,

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 0, dropped: 79, **fps: 0.00,** drop rate: 24.07

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 0, dropped: 79, **fps: 0.00,** drop rate: 24.07

/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFPSDisplaySink:fpsdisplaysink0: last-message = rendered: 0, dropped: 79, **fps: 0.00**, drop rate: 24.07

**I am totally confused, What is the problem with these two scenario's??**

Comment: I just found [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Performance-penalty-for-GStreamer-1-0-compared-to-0-10-td4664327.html) .. there is mentioned ORC.. do you have gstreamer compiled with ORC support? (ORC support enabled after compilation). What HW, OS do you use on that "Logitech"?

Comment: I am using RHEL 7.